# Согласование сказуемого с подлежащими, соединенными союзом "или"

Tags: согласование

В каком числе следует поставить сказуемое? Мне кажется, что на это влияет союз "или". Предложение такое:

*Наше нежелание разбираться в происходящих событиях или неспособность правильно их оценивать очень часто ограничива**ет**(-**ют**) понимание того, как развивается этот мир.*

Comment: Если ИЛИ - то ЕТ, если И - то ЮТ. Хотя у меня есть вопросы к содержанию фразы.

Comment: @Буратино, извините, Ваша правка неправильная. Подлежащими (какими?), соединенными.

Comment: А, ну может и так) я плохо читаю) читаю одно - думаю о другом)

Comment: Да, решение зависит от ИЛИ. Можно посмотреть у Розенталя §190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_08 Желательно множественное число "ограничиваЮТ".

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо за ссылку, понял.

Comment: *Это и это часто ограничивают. Это или это часто ограничивают.* Второе неверно, здесь нет выбора, здесь объединение.